# Getting warnings during SDF to PDB conversion using obabel?

Tags: cheminformatics

I did batch conversion of SDF to PDB for the Maybridge Screening library (containing ~50000 ligands) using `obabel` batch conversion tool using the following code.

```
 obabel *.sdf -opdb --gen3d -m
```

When I did it, I got **successfully the ligand converted** but I am getting a **few warning** referring to incorrect stating that `Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead`and wish to clarify the meaning of those warnings

```
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 5
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 2 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 4 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2 3 4
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1 12
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 1
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 2 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 11
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 3 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0 2 13
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 1 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 0
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
==============================
*** Open Babel Warning  in CorrectStereoAtoms
  Could not correct 5 stereocenter(s) in this molecule ()
  with Atom Ids as follows: 8 9 30 31 52
Warning: Stereochemistry is wrong, using the distance geometry method instead
```

What do these warnings stand for and how to handle these warnings?

Comment: Since you are using batch conversion you are getting warnings for more than one converted molecule. The software is apparently circumventing the encountered problem by applying an alternate algorithm to determine stereochemistry. While someone else here may know from experience what exactly the program is complaining about, you could help resolve the problem by narrowing it down to a specific example of a sdf formatted structure that triggers the warning. In other words, run the software on subsets until you find **one** structure that triggers the warning. Then post the sdf for that structure